# How to move shapes with the key buttons: up, left, down, right in delphi

Tags: delphi, key, shapes

first of all i'd like to apologise in advance if the title is not clear, so i will explain it.

I've created a shape, which you can move, by moving the mouse around, when you run the program:

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
begin
shape1.Left:=x;
shape1.Top:=y;
end;

end.
```

The thing is, that i didn't like it that the user has to use his mouse to move the shape, so i'd like to do it by pressing the key buttons UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, of the keyboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Just add an `OnKeyDown` event handler to the form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    VK_UP:
      Shape1.Top := Shape1.Top - 10;
    VK_DOWN:
      Shape1.Top := Shape1.Top + 10;
    VK_LEFT:
      Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left - 10;
    VK_RIGHT:
      Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left + 10;
  end;
end;
```

You might even do

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  Delta: integer;
begin
  if ssShift in Shift then
    Delta := 1
  else
    Delta := 10;
  case Key of
    VK_UP:
      Shape1.Top := Shape1.Top - Delta;
    VK_DOWN:
      Shape1.Top := Shape1.Top + Delta;
    VK_LEFT:
      Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left - Delta;
    VK_RIGHT:
      Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left + Delta;
  end;
end;
```

so that the user can fine-tune the position (with pixel precision) by holding the Shift key down.

Comment: the first one is not working, it says: incompatible types: integer and procedure untyped parameter

Comment: i told you what it says to me

Comment: @user2276109: Then I'm afraid you have made a mistake somewhere, possibly when you added your event handler.

Comment: Actually, sry, my mistake, the second one is workring, thank you, but i can't say the same about the first, thanks anyway

Comment: @user2276109: My code above works in any Delphi version. You have a syntax error somewhere in your code. I'm afraid I cannot tell you where without seeing your complete code.

Comment: @user2276109: I'm 100 % sure there is no error in the first code either. In fact, you obtain the first version by removing code (an additional feature) from the second one...

Comment: The first one is working too...i just forgot that i was not using application and a library was missing, thank you

Comment: I agree with you david, what do i have to do when my question is answered?

Comment: Click on the link in my comment. It explains everything.

Comment: First, read the [About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Then read the [Faq page](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Links are in the footer on every page, and for the faq also in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I hope I get this right, as it's been a while since I had to do Delphi, however:
- The Form object has a KeyDown or KeyPressed event to which you can react.
- AFAIK there is a "KeyPreview" property on the form as well which must be set to true for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a FireMonkey (FMX) solution.

---

Just add an `OnKeyDown` event handler to the form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    vkUp: Shape1.Position.Y := Shape1.Position.Y - 10;
    vkDown: Shape1.Position.Y := Shape1.Position.Y + 10;
    vkLeft: Shape1.Position.X := Shape1.Position.X - 10;
    vkRight: Shape1.Position.X := Shape1.Position.X + 10;
  end;
end;
```

You might even do

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  var Delta: Integer := 10;
  if ssShift in Shift then Delta := 1;

  case Key of
    vkUp: Shape1.Position.Y := Shape1.Position.Y - Delta;
    vkDown: Shape1.Position.Y := Shape1.Position.Y + Delta;
    vkLeft: Shape1.Position.X := Shape1.Position.X  - Delta;
    vkRight: Shape1.Position.X := Shape1.Position.X  + Delta;
  end;
end;
```

so that the user can fine-tune the position (with pixel precision) by holding the Shift key down.

---

There's also a way to do this using a `TTimer` component. Place a `TTimer` component onto the `Form` with the `Interval` set to `1` and then use the following code:

```
var
  Form1: TMainForm;
  UpPressed: Boolean;
  DownPressed: Boolean;
  LeftPressed: Boolean;
  RightPressed: Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UpPressed := False;
  DownPressed := False;
  LeftPressed := False;
  RightPressed := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    vkUp: UpPressed := True;
    vkDown: DownPressed := True;
    vkLeft: LeftPressed := True;
    vkRight: RightPressed := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  case Key of
    vkUp: UpPressed := False;
    vkDown: DownPressed := False;
    vkLeft: LeftPressed := False;
    vkRight: RightPressed := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if UpPressed then Shape1.Position.Y := Shape1.Position.Y - 10;
  if LeftPressed then Shape1.Position.X := Shape1.Position.X - 10;
  if RightPressed then Shape1.Position.X := Shape1.Position.X + 10;
  if DownPressed then Shape1.Position.Y := Shape1.Position.Y + 10;
end;
```

I personally prefer the `TTimer` solution.